# The Next iteration

Tags: php

I'm having some display problems here.

I have a "backend.php" file where I ask for two inputs.
These inputs are processed by "Addproducts.php" file and this file redirects to backend.php.

Backend.php also shows the current records in the database.

Here's the code for backend.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Inventory - Backend</title>

</head>
<body>

<form action="addproducts.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Product Name : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="pname"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product Quantity : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="productq"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="Add Product"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<h2>Current Products</h2>
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '') or die ('Unable to Connect.Check your connection parameters');
mysql_select_db('stock_inventory', $db) or die (mysql_error($db));
$query = 'SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS';
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Product ID </th>';
echo '<th>Producr Name </th>';
echo '<th>Product Stock </th>';
echo '</tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $row['product_id'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['product_name'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['product_stock'] . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<br/>';
echo '</table>';
}
else
{
echo "No products in the database";
}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

It displays something like this :-

```
Product ID  Producr Name    Product Stock
1           NewProduct  1
2HTC One5
3Samsung10
4Sony10
```

You see?
Only the first product is aligned, the rest are not.

How do I make them all align ?

Thanks.

Comment: I edited the question to make the output display as a code block; I can't figure out if it's showing the error correctly, though.

Comment: Close your table *outside* the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is you are closing your `table` tag within the loop, move it outside the loop like follows:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
  {
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>' . $row['product_id'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $row['product_name'] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $row['product_stock'] . '</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
  }
  else
  {
    echo "No products in the database";
  }
}
echo '<br/>';
echo '</table>';
```

Update: A better fix (see Barmar's comment below):

```
if (empty(mysql_num_row($result))) {
  echo "<tr><td colspan='3'>No products in the database</td></tr>";
} else {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['product_id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['product_name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['product_stock'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }
}
echo '</table>';
```

Also start looking into using `mysqli`(http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or `PDO` (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), `mysql_` is deprecated!

Comment: Also the `mysql_num_rows` check doesn't belong in the loop.

Comment: @Barmar, true.  I've added a better fix I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing the

> `<br/>`

from within your table. I believe that putting markup like line breaks inside of table markup will break the layout.